# How to design and implement the page like the below in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to design the paging  like the below.!UI page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/knAtQ.png
Please give me any samples like the above design .Have to design the paging like that and above need to show the "Show" dropdown and right side search filed.

Please let me know any samples like that design and implementation in MVC3?

Comment: -1 for effort. Consider using search to see if someone already tried to show data in a table with MVC... http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+data+table

Comment: I already designed my page .just need to include paging like that tell me solution

Comment: So you were asking about "paging"... It is not how your post reads (indeed it have word "paging" but to me it was misspelled "page" as title explicitly talks about page in general).

Comment: sorry paging is the correct one.

Comment: please provide me any samples to implement paging functionality like as in image with out using datatable plugin.

Comment: Note that "give me sample links" is generally off-topic on SO. Also you already got answer (and you even accepted it), but now you want more links that match some your secret criteria...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DataTable Plugin to do that.

[DataTable](http://datatables.net/)

[DataTable With Mvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part)

Comment: How to implement the paging like the above without Datatable pulgin ?provide me any sample links.

Comment: i need to show 1 to 10 outof 100 entries like that message also.like that any samples could you suggest.